# scrape data from interactive map

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the data from each pop-up on the map. I've used beautifulsoup in the past but this is a first getting data from an interactive map.

Any push in the right direction is helpful. So far i'm returning blanks.
Here's what i have, it isn't substantial...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests

url = 'https://www.oaklandconduit.com/development_map'
r = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs4(r, "html.parser")
address = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane"})
```

**Updated**
On recommendations, I went with parsing the javascript content with `re` using the script below. But loading into json returns an error

```
import requests, re
url = 'https://ebrrd.nationbuilder.com/themes/3/58597f55b92871671e000000/0/attachments/14822603711537993218/default/mapscript.js'
r = requests.get(url).content
content = re.findall(r'var.*?=\s*(.*?);', r, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)[2]
json_content = json.loads(content)
```

Comment: No, you can't use Beautiful Soup here, but you could parse the contents of this script: https://ebrrd.nationbuilder.com/themes/3/58597f55b92871671e000000/0/attachments/14822603711537993218/default/mapscript.js with re, and load it to json.

Comment: thanks for the direction @t.m.adam! I've been able to parse the contents using `re` but returns a _ValueError_ when loading to json. Any suggestions? I've updated the description with the current script

Comment: Your expression won't select all the data - there is a semicolon in a value (in "144 Residential Units;", line 734). You'll  have to include the next line ("// Add custom popups") in your regex. Also the  resulting json string is 'dirty'. You'll have to replace single quotes with double quotes and add quotes to a "type" key, and finally replace a leading tab in a value ('" To construct'), json won't tolerate it.

Comment: thanks for the nudge @t.m.adam. found a solution based on your assistance. open to feedback. many thanks.

Comment: That looks good! Some possible minor improvemrnts: You don't have to slice the content, just add `;\s*// Add custom popups` to your regex. You could just use `.replace` for the 'type'  keys. If  you use [`.text`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) for the response content your code will be Python3 compatible (`.content` is for binary data). You could demonstrate how to get data from `json_content`. I would use the titles as keys and coordinates (and maybe descriptions) as values.

Answer (score 1):

The interactive map is loaded through and driven by JavaScript, therefore, using the `requests` library is not going to be sufficient enough to get the data you want because it only gets you the initial response (in this case, HTML source code).

If you view the source for the page (on Chrome: `view-source:https://www.oaklandconduit.com/development_map`) you'll see that there is an empty div like so:

```
<div id='map'></div>
```

This is the placeholder div for the map.

You'll want to use a method that allows the map to load and for you to programmatically interact with it. [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) can do this for you but will be significantly slower than `requests` because it has to allow for this interactivity by launching a programmatically driven browser.

Answer (score 1):

Continued with regex to parse map contents into Json. Here's my approach with comments if helpful to others.

```
import re, requests, json
url = 'https://ebrrd.nationbuilder.com/themes/3/58597f55b92871671e000000/0/attachments/14822603711537993218/default' \
      '/mapscript.js'
r = requests.get(url).content
# use regex to get geoJSON and replace single quotes with double
content = re.findall(r'var geoJson.*?=\s*(.*?)// Add custom popups', r, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)[0].replace("'", '"')
# add quotes to key: "type" and remove trailing tab from value: "description"
content = re.sub(r"(type):", r'"type":', content).replace('\t', '')
# remove ";" from dict
content = content[:-5]
json_content = json.loads(content)
```

also open to other pythonic approaches.